# google_compute_instance_group Creation Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform

I am trying to create an instance group using the example in the terraform doc at https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance_group.html .

```
resource "google_compute_instance_group" "test" {
  name        = "terraform-test"
  description = "Terraform test instance group"
  zone        = "us-central1-a"
  network     = "${google_compute_network.default.self_link}"
  project ="xyz-project"
```

I get the following error:

> Error: resource 'google_compute_instance_group.test' config: unknown
>   resource 'google_compute_network.default' referenced in variable
>   google_compute_network.default.self_link

I've tried adding the following and get the same error.

```
data "google_compute_network" "default" {
  name = "default-us-east1"
```

Does anyone have a working example to create an instance group?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create an instance group using the following [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-lb/tree/master/examples/basic) which uses terraform. However, instruction in the example will also create TCP LB. You can refrain from creating the LB. Here are some additional tutorials using terraform [[1](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/managing-gcp-projects-with-terraform),[2](https://medium.com/@josephbleroy/using-terraform-with-google-cloud-platform-part-1-n-6b5e4074c059),[3]](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-examples) which might help you understand better.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
data "google_compute_network" "default" {
```

That means its created outside of terraform. It finds it and pulls it in via an API call. So in your `google_compute_instance_group` you need to make it

```
  network     = "${data.google_compute_network.default.self_link}"
```

Notice the `data` before `google`. This tells terraform its a datasource lookup and not a resource terraform is managing.